# How can I make files immutable in a docker container?

Tags: linux, docker

So I want to `chattr +i` on some important files in a docker container. But it doesn’t seem I can add the capability in `docker build`.  Now at runtime, I can `docker run --cap-add LINUX_IMMUTABLE`, but those attributes don’t seem to persist if I commit that attribute change to a new container. It’d be great if this worked, because after I set the attributes, I could run a new container without that capability, and I’d know my file could never become un-immutable.

So my question is, what’s the best way to make a file immutable in a container?  How can I prevent someone from bashing in to the container and changing sensitive files?

Comment: I don't think you can. If somebody can execute `docker` she can do everything, not only in containers but even on the host.

Comment: Good point, and I understand that. If someone on the host has access to the docker daemon, all bets are off, I’m more interested about in the context of the running container. Say the server I got running in a container gets compromised, and someone pops a shell inside my container. By default, they can mess with any files inside that container. But if I can set immutable flags, and then deny the container the ability to change that immutable flag, I could keep them from doing much damage.

Comment: Well you can make the whole filesystem read-only, for example by `docker run --read-only ...` - of course this might lead to some changes in your architecture. The problem is that AUFS does not support extended file attributes, and even if they were supported an attacker could just do a `chattr -i` to revert that. So making the whole filesystem read-only is the safest approach.

Comment: Whatever you do, please forbid chroot ;) https://fosterelli.co/privilege-escalation-via-docker.html. Or the immutability of files *inside* your container will be the *last* of your worries.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).